# Footer is not in the bottom (div-s overflow)

Tags: css, html, tags, overflow

Please see code below:

```
<div style="background:#F00;width:800px;">

<div style="float:left">
Hello  Hello  Hello  Hello  Hello  Hello  Hello  Hello  <br />
Hello  Hello  Hello  Hello  Hello  Hello  Hello  Hello  <br />
Hello  Hello  Hello  Hello  Hello  Hello  Hello  Hello  <br />
Hello  Hello  Hello  Hello  Hello  Hello  Hello  Hello  <br />
Hello  Hello  Hello  Hello  Hello  Hello  Hello  Hello  <br />
Hello  Hello  Hello  Hello  Hello  Hello  Hello  Hello  <br />
Hello  Hello  Hello  Hello  Hello  Hello  Hello  Hello  <br />
Hello  Hello  Hello  Hello  Hello  Hello  Hello  Hello  <br />
Hello  Hello  Hello  Hello  Hello  Hello  Hello  Hello  <br />
Hello  Hello  Hello  Hello  Hello  Hello  Hello  Hello  <br />
Hello  Hello  Hello  Hello  Hello  Hello  Hello  Hello  <br />
Hello  Hello  Hello  Hello  Hello  Hello  Hello  Hello  <br />
Hello  Hello  Hello  Hello  Hello  Hello  Hello  Hello  <br />
Hello  Hello  Hello  Hello  Hello  Hello  Hello  Hello  <br />
Hello  Hello  Hello  Hello  Hello  Hello  Hello  Hello  <br />


</div>

<div style="float:right">
Thanks!
</div>


</div>

<div id="footer">
footer
</div>
```

I have two sections and I want the footer be in the bootom of first child div of body tag. But I don't want to give height to any div, as they should be aligned to their content. How can I do this?

EDIT:

Seems that footer div does not consider the computed height of the other divs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to clear the float of the first div child.

2 ways of doing it i think.

1) right after `<div style="float:right">Thanks!</div>`
add:

```
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

2) change footer to:

```
<div id="footer" style="clear: both">
footer
</div>
```

Comment: then u might need to show us the relevant real code. maybe the html markup in ur real code is so much different?

Comment: The problem was that I gave height to one of divs. Removed the height and it worked! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You might also add try adding `style="float: left; width: 100%"` to `footer`. Perhaps that will work around whatever conflicts are preventing Shadow_boi's solutions to work.